# Progressive draw to canvas

Tags: flutter

I'm looking into progressive draw to canvas in flutter.

I know about CustomPainter, but somehow the canvas gets cleared between the two paint events.

What I'm looking is to add just changes to the canvas, not drawing everything that has to be drawn on canvas. Imagine a sketch app where I'd just add new lines to the canvas instead of redrawing it each time paint is requested.

Comment: That's certainly an option. But won't there be a perf penalty for that?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to simply draw over existing image, even creating an in memory image looks difficult. Hm

Comment: I don't think that will work as well. Once you end recording, the picture is sealed. And that's the only way to get a Picture out of it.

Comment: Right, creating a picture per event. That'd probably work, will try it and see how it is performing compared to drawing on each step directly to canvas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190226/discussion-between-miha-markic-and-pskink).

Comment: Could you share what your solution is?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, it was ages ago and not sure if I kept it. If I find it then I'll  share.